# How to return value from backing bean as composite component attribute

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have the following JSF composite component:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComp">
    <composite:attribute name="input" type="java.lang.Integer" />
    <composite:attribute name="output" type="java.lang.Integer" />
    <composite:attribute name="action" method-signature="java.lang.String action()"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.input}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Assuming the composite is invoked as

```
<h:form id="form">
    <cc:myComposite id="cc" input="#{bean.input}" 
                    output="#{bean.output}" action="#{bean.action}"  />
</h:form>
```

Once `bean.action` is invoked it sets a value in `bean.output`. I need to access this value in my javascript, something like this

```
document.getElementById('form:cc:output').value
```

From myComp I can set the attribute with

```
getAttributes().put("output", output);
```

But the data resides in the backing bean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a component to submit the 'output' value to the backing bean.  Use inputHidden to accomplish this:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComp">
  <composite:attribute name="input" type="java.lang.Integer" />
  <composite:attribute name="output" type="java.lang.Integer" />
  <composite:attribute name="action" method-signature="java.lang.String action()"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
  <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.input}" />
  <h:inputHidden id="output" value="#{cc.attrs.output}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Then you'll be able to set the 'output' value using its hidden input element via javascript.

Comment: You mean to set the output attribute via javascript or to retrieve it?  I'm looking for the latter, something like `var x = document.getElementById('form:cc:output').value;`